# How can a multiplication table be displayed using only nested for loops and System.out.println in Java?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, nested

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{       
    int q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;

    for (q=1; q<=10; q++)
    { 
        System.out.print("\t" + q);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (r=2; r<=20; r += 2)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + r);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (s=3; s<=30; s += 3)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + s);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (t=4; t<=40; t += 4)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + t);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (u=5; u<=50; u += 5)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + u);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (v=6; v<=60; v += 6)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + v);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (w=7; w<=70; w += 7)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + w);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (x=8; x<=80; x += 8)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + x);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (y=9; y<=90; y += 9)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + y);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (z=10; z<=100; z += 10)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + z);
    }

}
```

Despite how ridiculous this program looks, it displays a multiplication table in the desired format. Being a noob (as you can see) and trying to learn these nested loops has been very confusing, especially when the tutorial says that this multiplication table, in the same exact format, can be written using just nested for loops and System.out.println. The tutorial is not the least bit helpful and gives a rather simple use of nested for loops and right now I cannot see how it's applicable in simplifying this program....but it says it can be done so it can.

Comment: Maybe: This ? http://pastebin.com/TrJtidjY

Comment: @Aaron I'm not seeing any nested loops here

Comment: 1  2  3 4  5  6 7  8 9 10 the line under that would be                2 4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20...the formatting on this comment section doesn't quite do it justice but it should follow this pattern all the way to line 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that you will learn in any beginners book:

```
for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
  for (int j=1;j<=10;j++)
     System.out.print("\t"+i*j);
  System.out.println(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as you expected using array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[][] array = new int[11][11];
for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
for (int j=1; j<array[i].length; j++) {
array[i][j] = i*j;
System.out.print(" " + array[i][j]);
}
System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this: -

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= 10 * i; j += i) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
   }
```

Comment: Please check this is not printing multiplication table 1-10.

Comment: @sunleo Sorry a typo. Edited .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this with pretty printing (individual cells right/left justified):

```
private static void printMultiplicationTable(int m, int n) {
    int[][] arr = new int[m][n];
    int[] maxes = new int[n];

    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (int j = i, k = 1; j <= n * i; j += i) {
            arr[i-1][k-1] = j;
            if ((maxes[k-1]+"").length() < (j+"").length()) {
                maxes[k-1] = (j+"").length();
            }
            k++;
        }
   }

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print(adjust(arr[i][j], maxes[j], true) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static String adjust(int n, int tot, boolean rightJustify) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i=1; i<=tot - (n + "").length(); i++) {
        buff.append(" ");
    }

    if (rightJustify) {
        buff.append(n);
        return buff.toString();
    } else {
        return n + buff.toString();
    }
}
```